# Is there a way to get table contents from 3rd party UWP application?

Tags: windows, winapi, uwp

There is UWP application which has a table with data and no built-in way to export it anyhow.
Is there a way to "spy" on the window to at least get raw text content of the table, or all text of whole window?

Can WinAPI be used here, I wonder? Even the most "perverted" way will do.

*EDIT:* To clarify,

acceptable case: to get table contents "manually" as temporary measure;

desired case: to get table contents from within my own application.

Comment: Attach a debugger and dump the process memory, I guess. As it's a XAML application you should be able to use the Live Visual Tree tool in Visual Studio and use the Immediate window to write a Linq expression to dump the contents of the UI.

Comment: @Dai thanks. why you answered in comment tho? =)

Comment: Becuase it's an informed-guess that makes many assumptions about your scenario. Additionally I'm not a UWP expert - so I didn't want to risk being downvoted :)

Comment: And such an answer would have been downvoted. Not a good idea at all.

Comment: @Dai: UWP does not equate to XAML. There are many applications (specifically those based on C++/WinRT), where the debugger will not display the Live Visual Tree, because the program does not use XAML controls.

Comment: Unclear, why there is a [tag:wpf] tag. It's either UWP or WPF. Make up your mind.

Comment: IInspectable My bad, mixed things up because of tiredness and uncertainty about what I deal with, UWP or WPF. In the end it didn't matter, in place of Live Visual Tree, I've got DOM tree, following same routine @Dai advised, so thanks.

Comment: @IInspectable If I understand right it was luck i've got DOM tree. If you don't mind, i ask you for advice: do I edit the question to make it better and how? I'll add clarifications from this comments to accepted answer, I guess, but question seems vague to me, altho I've had no more data to improve it. I've omited a nuance, which could have been (and was, as anwer shows) deducted and I fix it now. Can you recommend anything besides?

Comment: *"Can WinAPI be used here?"* is not a good question. Anything that can be done on Windows is done through the Windows API, one way or another (leaving driver development and the Native API aside). It's also not a good question, because answering it (*"Yes."*) is not entirely helpful either. The question is also lacking detail about the target application (e.g. does it use standard controls?)

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a tool to see the UI contents, `Windows SDK Inspect.exe` could help you.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318521(v=vs.85).aspx

If you want to write a program to interact with UI contents, use the `Windows UIAutomation` library. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009(v=vs.85).aspx. Previous url also shows some info on UIAutomation.

Comment: Thanks, your both suggestions work. Inspector.EXE was useful to get a proof of concept and as of now I see that UI Automation will do. As I understand, there is no lightweight (from coding perspective) analogue to this? UI Automation is kinda overkill right now, in all its glory.

Comment: That would be asking the 3rd party for some API to access their contents